# Jailbroken iPhone: Application Delegate Methods not Found on Device

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uuid, jailbreak

In the simulator, I don't have this problem but when I run the app on my device `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillTerminate` aren't called. Is it because I'm jailbroken and running backgrounder etc? Here's the gdb log from Xcode:

```
    [Session started at 2010-02-28 15:37:00 +0900.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1460) (Fri Feb  5 06:29:49 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys006
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-582-78
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11779]
[Switching to thread 11779]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
continue
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
 /Volumes/Xcode/MyAppName/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/RockExtensions/RockExtensions.dylib" (file not found).
2010-02-28 15:37:26.270 MyAppName[997:207] MS:Notice: Installing: com.yourcompany.MyAppName [MyAppName] (478.52)
2010-02-28 15:37:26.423 MyAppName[997:207] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1 (7C144)/Symbols/usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
2010-02-28 15:37:26.654 MyAppName[997:207] MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/FCSB.dylib
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/FCSB.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/RockExtensions/RockInject.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1 (7C144)/Symbols/usr/lib/librockextension.dylib" (file not found).
2010-02-28 15:37:27.112 MyAppName[997:207] RE:Notice: Launching: com.yourcompany.MyAppName
MS:Warning: message not found [MyAppName applicationWillResignActive:]
MS:Warning: message not found [MyAppName applicationDidBecomeActive:]
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Please try if you can debug it in safe mode (`killall -SEGV SpringBoard`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
 /Volumes/Xcode/MyAppName/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
```

...is the kiss of death for a jailbreak project. It means that none of your paths, which are built from the UUID, will resolve. On the device, the loader literally cannot find the paths to the necessary files.

There's supposed to be something in the jailbreak tool chain to compensate for this but I don't remember what it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not writing a JB project, it's just that my phone is JB.

Comment: I pretty sure jail breaking the phone alters its paths. On the other hand, I don't know much about working on jailbroke devices so don't take that is gospel. I do know this is a common problem on jailbroken devices, though.