# unable to read symbols for

Tags: ios, debugging, frameworks, device, symbols

You guys have helped me on number of occasions and I need you once more.

Every time I want to debug my app on device I get following warnings and app doesn't proceed ahead of splash screen.

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).
>
> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
>   (file not found).
>
> Unable to read symbols for
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3
>   (8J2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file
>   not found).

there is no SIGBART, BAD_EXCESS, ERROR massages. this problem is not for one specific app but all three app I am working on.
I am using xcode 4.0 and my IPhone 3GS has iOS version 4.3.3

I have restarted my xcode and device also but no good news.

Thanks in advance for every good suggestion.

Comment: Jailbroken? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350369/jailbroken-iphone-application-delegate-methods-not-found-on-device

Comment: on the thread you have mentioned only problem is stated, there is not any solution for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` and delete `4.3.3 (8J2)` folder. Connect your device and open xcode and select use for development

Comment: I did that. on reconnecting the device xcode collected the new symbols  but it didn't solve my problem. warning remains the same.

Comment: try to do it again and restart mac and iphone and connect iphone to mac and collect sysmbols again...